Why does ISchedulerLIstener.JobDeleted fire twice for each job?
I am creating my jobs from a database table and adding a simple Schedule Listener.
        // Create, configure and start the scheduler.
        this.scheduler = await this.schedulerFactory.GetScheduler(cancellationToken);
        this.scheduler.JobFactory = this.jobFactory;
        this.scheduler.ListenerManager.AddSchedulerListener(this.schedulerListener);
        await this.scheduler.Start(cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);

        // Schedule each the persistent jobs.
        foreach (var jobSchedule in this.dataModel.JobSchedules)
        {
            try
            {
                // Create the job.
                var job = jobSchedule.Job;
                var type = Type.GetType(job.Type);
                ArgumentNullException.ThrowIfNull(type);
                var jobDetail = JobBuilder.Create(type)
                    .WithIdentity(new JobKey(job.Name, job.Group))
                    .Build();

                // Create the trigger.
                var trigger = jobSchedule.Trigger;
                var quartzTriggerBuilder = TriggerBuilder
                    .Create()
                    .WithIdentity(new TriggerKey(trigger.Name, trigger.Group));

                // Add the CRON scheduler.
                if (trigger.CronSchedule != null)
                {
                    if (trigger.TimeZone == null)
                    {
                        quartzTriggerBuilder.WithCronSchedule(trigger.CronSchedule);
                    }
                    else
                    {
                        quartzTriggerBuilder
                            .WithCronSchedule(
                            trigger.CronSchedule,
                            x => x.InTimeZone(TimeZoneInfo.FindSystemTimeZoneById(trigger.TimeZone)));
                    }
                }

                var quartzTrigger = quartzTriggerBuilder.Build();

                // Schedule the job.
                await this.scheduler.ScheduleJob(jobDetail, quartzTrigger, cancellationToken).ConfigureAwait(false);
            }
            catch (Exception exception)
            {
                this.logger.LogError(exception, "{message}", exception.Message);
            }
        }

The listener implementation is simply:
    public async Task JobDeleted(JobKey jobKey, CancellationToken cancellationToken = default)
    {
            this.logger.LogError("{message}", $"Deleting job ({jobKey.Group},{jobKey.Name})");
    }

This fires twice for every job I have running. I've verified that there is only one job running by putting logging statements on the jobs.
Why does it fire twice?
